# не работает переключения "case" между скриптами питон

Tags: python

Мои переключения между скриптами не работают от слова совсем

```
from secrets import choice
from selenium import *
from time import *
from get_data import * 
from pars import *

def step_init():
    print('''
    1. Парсинг
    2. Добавление нового абонента
''')

def input_param():
    string = input("Выберите тип операции : ")

    match string: 
        case "parsing":
            parsing()
        case "add":
            stable()

first = step_init()
second = input_param()
```

Сначала должен отрабатываться **принт**, потом **инпут** и в зависимости от инпута должен срабатывать **case** который запустит один из двух файлов с скриптами.

Но почему то сначала скрипты срабатывают по очереди, и уж в конце светится выбор инпута. Как мне исправить?

---

упростил логику через условия до следующего, но результат неизменный!!!! Может тут что посоветуете?

```
from pkgutil import get_data
from secrets import choice
from selenium import *
from time import *
from get_data import * 
from pars import *

x = input('''Enter the number of operation : 
    1. Parsing
    2. Add client 
''')

if x == '1': 
    parsss()
elif x == '2':
    parsing()
else:
    print('!!! No such operation !!!')
```

**файл get_data.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

class SBMS_start():
    def open(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe')
        self.browser.get('website')
        self.browser.maximize_window()

    def auth(self):
        browser = self.browser
        sleep(1)
        username_textbox = browser.find_element_by_name("user")
        username_textbox.send_keys("login")     #LOGIN
        sleep(1)
        password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.send_keys("pass")       #PASSWORD
        sleep(1)
        button1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div[5]/button')#ENTER
        button1.click() 

    def search_btn(self):
        browser= self.browser
        sleep(1)
        search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ps-button[1]')
        search.click()

    def parse(self):
        browser = self.browser

        #-----------------------------------------------------------CLIENT INFORMATION--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        sleep(1)
        name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[1]')
        adress = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]')
        jur_type = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]')
        type = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[4]')
        gender = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[5]')
        birth = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[6]')
        document = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[7]')
        serial = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[8]')
        serial_number = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[9]')
        given = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[10]')
        given_date = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[11]')
        balance = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]')

        #-----------------------------------------------------------ABONENT INFORMATION--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ms_log = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr')
        tarif = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]')
        main_balance = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[2]')
        number_class = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[4]')
        number_type = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[5]')
        kommutator = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[6]')
        icc = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[7]')
        imsi = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[8]')
        activ_date = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[9]')
        last_pay = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[12]')
        last_sum = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody[5]/tr[13]')
        print('\n') #client info
        print('-----------------Client Information--------------')
        print(name.text)
        print(adress.text)
        print(jur_type.text)
        print(type.text)
        print(gender.text)
        print(birth.text)
        print(document.text)
        print(serial.text)
        print(serial_number.text)
        print(given.text)
        print(given_date.text)
        print(balance.text)
        print('\n') #abon info
        print('-----------------Abonent Information--------------')
        print('\n') #abon info
        print(ms_log.text)
        print(tarif.text)
        print(main_balance.text)
        print(number_class.text)
        print(number_type.text)
        print(kommutator.text)
        print(icc.text)
        print(imsi.text)
        print(activ_date.text)
        print(last_pay.text)
        print(last_sum.text)

class ms():
    def msisdn_put():
        sleep(1)
        pyautogui.moveTo(400,190,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(400,190,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.write("998118971")    #input of msisdn
        sleep(1)

def parsing():
    start =SBMS_start()
    start.open()
    start.auth()

    sleep(1)
    mouse = ms()
    ms.msisdn_put()

    start.search_btn()
    start.parse()

blabla = parsing()
```

**файл  pars.py**

```
from functools import wraps
from os import write
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

class SBMS():
    def start(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe')
        self.browser.maximize_window()
        self.browser.get('website')

    def auth(self):
        browser = self.browser
        sleep(1)
        username = browser.find_element_by_name("user")
        username.send_keys("login")
        sleep(1)
        password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.send_keys("pass")
        sleep(1)
        autorisation = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div[5]/button')
        autorisation.click() #ENTER
    
    def search(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ps-button[1]').click()

    def registration(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SHELL_MENU.ITEM0040"]/a').click()

    def add_abon(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu-CLIR.ITEM0020"]').click()

    def regular_msisdn(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PS_SBMS_WORK_WINDOW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ng-form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ps-radio-group/label[2]/span[2]').click()

    def kommutator(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PS_SBMS_WORK_WINDOW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ng-form/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div').click()
    
    def gsm_hw(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PS_SBMS_WORK_WINDOW"]/div[10]/div/ps-list-item[2]/div').click()

    def free_numbers(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PS_SBMS_WORK_WINDOW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ng-form/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/div/div/div[2]/ps-list-item[74]/div').click()

    def sim_cart(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PS_SBMS_WORK_WINDOW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ng-form/div[1]/div[2]/ps-splitter/ps-splitter-zone[2]/div/ps-tabs/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()

    def find(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PS_SBMS_WORK_WINDOW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ng-form/div[2]/div/ps-button[1]').click()

    def cancel(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ps-button[2]').click()

class mouse_move():
    def initialise():
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 1.5
        pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True 

        pyautogui.size()
        pyautogui.position()

        pyautogui.moveTo(370,190,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(370,190,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.write("777772194")    #input of msisdn

    def triple_dots():
        pyautogui.moveTo(687,244,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(687,244,duration=0.5)

    def find():
        pyautogui.moveTo(637,860,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(637,860,duration=0.5)

    def msisdn():
        pyautogui.moveTo(876,777,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(876,777,duration=0.5)

    def ICC():
        pyautogui.moveTo(865,675,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(865,675,duration=0.5)

class stable():
    def stage():
        start1 = SBMS()
        start1.start()
        start1.auth()

        mouse = mouse_move()
        mouse_move.initialise()

        start1.search()
        sleep(1)
        start1.registration()
        sleep(1)
        start1.add_abon()

        sleep(1)
        mouse_move.triple_dots()

        sleep(1)
        start1.regular_msisdn()
        sleep(1)
        start1.kommutator()
        sleep(1)
        start1.gsm_hw()
        sleep(1)
        start1.free_numbers()

        sleep(1)
        mouse_move.find()

        sleep(1)
        mouse_move.msisdn()

        sleep(1)
        start1.sim_cart()

        sleep(1)
        mouse_move.ICC()

        sleep(1)
        start1.find()
        sleep(5)
        start1.cancel()

def parsss():
    go = stable()
    stable.stage()

parss = parsss()
```

Comment: С точки зрения показанного вами скрипта все должно работать именно так как вы описали, сначала input, потом запуск функций parsing/stable в зависимости от выбора. Если это не так, значит ваши скрипты срабатывают еще при import, а тогда надо смотреть не данный скрипт выбора и те скрипты в которых описаны функции parsing и stable

Comment: добавьте исходники ваших собственных модулей. (я так понимаю `get_data` и `pars` вы сами писали.)

Comment: @n1tr0xs так точно писал сам. get_data хранит скпипт по добавлению новых клиентов а pars содержит скрипт для парсинга данных по имеющимся анкетам. Код выше предназначен для выбора того или инога скрипта для запуска. Но на деле получается что оба скрипта без выбора на старте запускается один за другим после того как завершится первый

Comment: @n1tr0xs сделал как вы просили, добавил оба файла с скриптами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В подключаемых скриптах всё, что не должно сразу выполняться при подключении, должно быть обёрнуто в такую проверку:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Например, вы делаете такой импорт:

```
from pars import *
```

Файл `pars.py` у вас заканчивается таким кодом:

```
def parsss():
    go = stable()
    stable.stage()

parss = parsss()
```

Этот код **сразу выполнится** при таком импорте. Но я так понимаю, вы этого не хотите при импорте, вы хотите, чтобы импортировались только функции из этого файла. Тогда вы должны оформить этот файл так:

```
def parsss():
    go = stable()
    stable.stage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parss = parsss()
```

В этом случае строка `parss = parsss()` выполнится только если запускать сам скрипт `pars.py`. А если его импортировать, эта строка уже не будет выполняться.

Тоже самое нужно сделать со всеми вашими файлами, которые вы импортируете. В стандартных библиотеках такие проверки уже есть, если они там нужны.

Comment: помогло. До этого попробовал удалить вызов методов в самих файлах с скриптами, но знал что это не совсем корректно